# Core dump: how to determine version of crashed application

Tags: version-control, coredump

I need to strictly bind every core file generated by system to certain bin version of crashed application. I can specify core-name pattern in sysctl.conf:kernel.core_pattern, but there is no way to put bin version here.

How can I put the version of crashed program into core file (revision number) or any other way to determine version of the crashed binary?

I'm using qmake VERSION variable in .pro file, which contains revision number from SVN. Its available by `QCoreApplication::applicationVersion()`, in my every binary by passing the command option flag `--version`.

Comment: What exactly is a bin version? Do you keep some variable somewhere in the executable that needs to be extracted to get the version number?

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323272/embedding-version-info-in-executable-and-retrieving-it-from-linux-core-dump). Will not work as a generic solution, but may work fine for your own app. In short: create some static string variable with a unique prefix and the version, like `v = "MYAPPVER_" + QCoreApplication::applicationVersion()` and then grep core dump strings against this prefix `strings coredump | grep MYAPPVER`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding version info in executable and retrieving it from Linux core dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323272/embedding-version-info-in-executable-and-retrieving-it-from-linux-core-dump)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using qmake VERSION variable in .pro file, which contains revision number from SVN. Its available by QCoreApplication::applicationVersion(), in my every bin by flag --version.

Assuming your app can get far enough to print out its version number without a core dump, you can write a small program (python would probably be easiest) that is invoked by a core dump. The program would read stdin, dump it to a file, then rename the file based on the version number.

From man 5 core:

```
Piping core dumps to a program
       Since  kernel  2.6.19,  Linux  supports  an  alternate  syntax  for the
       /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file.  If the  first  character  of  this
       file  is  a  pipe  symbol (|), then the remainder of the line is inter‐
       preted as a program to be executed.  Instead of being written to a disk
       file,  the  core  dump is given as standard input to the program.  Note
       the following points:

       *  The program must be specified using an absolute pathname (or a path‐
          name relative to the root directory, /), and must immediately follow
          the '|' character.

       *  The process created to run the program runs as user and group root.

       *  Command-line arguments can be supplied to the program  (since  Linux
          2.6.24),  delimited by white space (up to a total line length of 128
          bytes).

       *  The command-line arguments can  include  any  of  the  %  specifiers
          listed  above.   For example, to pass the PID of the process that is
          being dumped, specify %p in an argument.
```

If you call your script /usr/local/bin/dumper, then

```
echo "| /usr/local/bin/dumper %E" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

The dumper should copy stdin to a file, then try to run the program named on its command line to extract a version number and use that to rename the file.

Something like this might work (I haven't tried it, so use at extreme risk:)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os,subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

CORE_FNAME="/tmp/core"

with open(CORE_FNAME,"f") as f:
    while buf=sys.stdin.read(10000):
        f.write(buf)

pname=sys.argv[1].replace('!','/')
out=subprocess.check_output([pname, "--version"])
version=out.split('\n')[0].split()[-1]
os.rename(CORE_FNAME, CORE_FNAME+version)
```

The really big risk of doing this is recursive core dumps that may crash your system. Be sure to use ulimit to only allow core dumps from processes that can print out their own versions without core dumping.

It would be a good idea to change the script to re-run the program to get the version info **only** if it is the program you are expecting.